# C#: Assign test result directly to variable

Tags: c#, variables, if-statement, boolean-logic

Is it possible to assign the result of a test directly to a variable?

I want to do something like

```
c = ( a == b )
```

instead of

```
if ( a == b )
{
 c = true;
}
 else
{
 c = false;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: put it into C# compiler before asking, the answer it's YES

Comment: Have you tried it to see if it works?

Comment: Well... I feel a bit stupid now. For some reason, it didn't work when I was testing it in the compiler. Sorry guys. >.>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course.

Which you can very easily test with the compiler.

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
bool c = a == b;
```