# I don't understand a piece of someones answer

Tags: c#

This is an odd question but in someones else's answer in a different question they posted the following

```
try
{
   PingReply reply = pinger.Send(nameOrAddress);
   pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
}
```

How does `pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;` work? To me that looks like an if statement without the if.

Comment: `pingable` is a boolean variable. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18183591) from earlier today.

Comment: You should really include a link to the answer in question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
reply.Status == IPStatus.Success
```

will return a `boolean` which will be assigned to `pingable` variable.

Same thing will happen inside `if` statement: First the expression will be calculated, with `true` or `false` as a result, and only the result will be checked as branch condition.

Comment: Thank you.  I did not know that you could do stuff like this without actually writing out an if statement.  I am always looking for ways to make code look cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Same as

```
if(reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    pingable = true;
else
    pingable = false;
```

The code

```
reply.Status == IPStatus.Success
```

returns a boolean that is inserted in pingable.

Answer (score 2):

(reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) evaluates as a boolean true or false

Answer (score 1):

the operator `==` always resolves to a boolean

so

```
pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
```

puts `true` in `pingable` if `reply.Status` and `IPStatus.Success` are equal, and it puts `false` in `pingable` if they are not.

Answer (score 1):

It is a condition. `pingable` is boolean.

Answer (score 0):

`pingable` (as boolean) is set to if `reply.Status` is equal to `IPStatus.Sucess`